# Finding Angular/Ionic HttpClient system/network error code/message (not HTTP status code)

Tags: angular, networking, error-handling, httpclient

I’m having problems getting meaningful Angular HttpClient system/network error messages (not HTTP status codes) out so I can log/report them. I have a provider with code similar to:

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

getData() {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(this.url)
        .pipe(
            retry(3),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errmsg:string;
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        errmsg = `client/network error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
        errmsg = `server error: ${error.status}: ${error.error}`;
    }
    console.error(errmsg);
    return new ErrorObservable(errmsg);
}
```

Running app with ionic serve, works under normal conditions but when I stop my Tomcat server any useful diagnostic info gets lost before it gets to handleError().

Javascript console shows:

```
GET https... net::ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (at polyfills.js:3)
```

The handleError() console message from the JSON.stringify() includes:

```
status: 0
statusText: Unknown Error
name: HttpErrorResponse
message: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
```

The console.error(errmsg) at the end of handleError() produces:

```
server error 0: [object ProgressEvent]
```

What am I missing? How can I get a proper error code/message in my hands that I can do something useful with? I'd like to be able to log a useful error message that indicates DNS error or connection refused or whatever, things that aren't covered by HTTP status codes.

Thanks…

Comment: You already have this. status and statusText are those data you need. The thing is that status 0 indicates in this cenario that some not expected error has happened (example: your device doesn't have internet/wifi access). Once you have this access problem fixed, the other errors will come with more meaningful data (example: status 500, statusText with the webserver output error/message).

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. In this case polyfills.js knows it was a connection refused error but all my error handler sees is error 0 (unknown error), so I can't log/alert the more detailed cause. There's a lot of scenarios between/including dead wi-fi and getting enough of a connection to my Tomcat server that it can provide meaningful status codes. Status 0 could mean a lot of things and I want to be able to determine which of those things happened so I can provide meaningful diagnostics or suggest remedies to the user.

Comment: I think to be able to grab more meaningful errorCode, you'd need to actually respond the meaningful error to the frontend in the first place. Are you doing that right now from your backend? If yes, you then can get the "error" response from `HttpErrorResponse.error` and you can also start looking into Interceptor to process the responses before it even goes into your Error handler.

Comment: Back end is returning status code/message (e.g. 404 not found) when it encounters an error, and the front end is handling these errors.

Problem is handling errors where the request doesn't make it to the back end, and the back end has no chance to provide an error code/message (e.g. bogus hostname in the request URL, host unreachable, web service out to lunch. I want to be able to provide a more meaningful error message than 0:unknown error.

Better error info is in polyfills.js (logged in console log), but how can I get that info into my app where I can deal with it?